# Spring Entity Postgres Point Field

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I started a JHipster project and have an entity called Question that has a point field. I don't really care what kind of Point class I'm using, but I've tried them all, `org.postgresql.geometric.PGPoint`, [org.geolatte.geom.Point](https://github.com/realityforge/geolatte-geom-jpa), custom point class with converter and to no end.

`@Column(name = "location") @Convert(converter=PointConverter.class)
private Point location;`

I'm now trying to use the geolatte `PostgisConverter<Point>` but I also have a QuestionDTO class. Can I/Should I add a converter on

I get the following exception when trying to save a question instance:

`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of org.geolatte.geom.Point: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.geolatte.geom.Point: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6ec2b023; line: 8, column: 7] (through reference chain: com.dumdums.askaround.service.dto.QuestionDTO["location"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:244)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:229)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)`

Any example I could see or advice on to how to map this field? I'm using point in postgresql in order to do [cube/eartdistance](http://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/08/how-far-is-the-nearest-pub/) queries so that I cannot change.

Comment: What I have done in the past: have two float fields to represent the point with latitude and longitude. If on the DB side there is a need to operate with spatial data, I added a trigger on the table to populate the spatial field based on the incoming lat and long (or have a view for that).  Similarly on the entity side:  Point can be a calculated field or populated during construction.  There is probably a better way, but this way I had none of these special type conversion issues.

Comment: JPA has nothing at all to do with this. This is JSON. Just look at the stack trace!

Comment: JPA has everything to do with this. I don't insist on using PGPoint. I'd be happy with any object that can be automatically mapped to postgresql point, but everything I tried ended up in some kind of error.

Comment: The only/easiest way I could make this work was by using PointType and Point from this project: https://github.com/The-Alchemist/hibernate-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue can be resolved by supplying the default constructor in your value object **QuestionDTO**

Please check do you have the default constructor available 
Also, please check the setter visibility of the location member if available.

Comment: That's not a choice since org.geolatte.geom.Point is a class in a library. I did think about extending it and adding the default constructor and setters but I think I'm missing something else since the Readme says it should work out of the box

Comment: @VladTopala This was in reference to : QuestionDTO , is it having default constructor ?

Comment: Yes, QuestionDTO does have a default constructor. Not sure why you would think that's the problem since the exception says `JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of org.geolatte.geom.Point: no suitable constructor found`